# Make application startup with size and position it was when it was closed

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm currently creating a application that, when it reopens need to have the same size and screen position as just before it was closed.

I hope that it is just a checkmark in interface builder that i haven't noticed.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement **Application Persistence**.

Read more [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/07/whats-new-for-developers-in-lion-part-1/).

When a user logs out, Lion offers them the option to restore all open apps to their current state when logging back in. To support this feature in your app you must determine for each window whether its state should be preserved using the -setRestorable: method. Cocoa will then take care of saving the state (size, position, etc.) of your windows and their associated window controllers, giving you the option to write out additional state information of custom objects associated with the windows.

To restore your application’s state when it is relaunched, every window must specify a so-called restoration class through the +restoreWindowWithIdentifier:state:completionHandler: class method (defined in the NSWindowRestoration protocol). The restoration class is then responsible for instantiating the window and its associated objects (such as the window controller). See the User Interface Preservation topic in the Mac OS X Application Programming Guide for a step by step guide.

Comment: Hi,

I haven't used methods before. Can you please explain how i should implement this into my code? :-)

Comment: I have given the link. have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

Close to a checkbox. Set the window's frame auto-save name. That's a key naming a value in the app's preferences (which is managed by `NSWindow`) under which the window's frame is stored and retrieved.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't help to set a Autosave name :-(

Can it maybe be because I use:
- (BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)application
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Are you calling something like `-center` or a `-setFrame...` method? What are you using to show the window? (Or is it in your MainMenu.xib and is marked as visible at launch?)

Comment: I don't call neither -center nor -setframe 

To show it, I have marked it as visible at launch :-)

Answer (score 0):

Store size and position in NSUserDefaults.For example you store a cgpoint in Nsuserdefaults
as follows

```
CGPoint *point=CGPointMake(34,67);
NSUserDefaults* def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* mypointstr=NSStringFromCGPoint(point);
[def SetObject:mypointstr:forkey:@"mypoint"];
```

to get this next time the app starts

```
NSString* myprevstr=[def Objectforkey:@"mypoint"]
CGPoint* point=CGPointFromString(myprevstr);
```